# Asp.Net boilerplate Hangfire Integration .Net Core

Tags: hangfire, aspnetboilerplate

I have an Abp 3.3.4 project based on the SPA template. I don't use the Angular UI. Now I want to integrate Hangfire to handle emails sending and I need a few quick pointers:

1. In which project do I install [Abp.HangFire.AspNetCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Abp.HangFire.AspNetCore) Hangfire? `Sample.Core` or
   `Sample.Web.Core` or `Sample.Web.Host` or `Sample.Application` project?
2. Do I need to create background jobs from the same project in which I
   install Hangfire? For instance, If I install Hangfire in
   `Sample.Web.Core`, can I create email jobs from `Sample.Core`?

Note: I still want to use the Hangfire dashboard.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have to reference it to Sample.Web.Core project.
2. Yes you need to create the jobs in Sample.Web.Core project.  You cannot create it from Sample.Core.

Comment: Perfect. Trying now will get back on this in a moment.